# Baking rigid body physics - Blender 3.0

Tags: rigidbody

This is probably a basic question but I can't find an answer that is relevant to Blender 3.0

I baked an animation with rigid body physics and particle physics for 300 frames.
I now want to extend the animation to 400 frames. The particle simulation keeps going but the rigid body simulation still stops at 300.

How do I re-bake the rigid body physics again so that the action keeps going for 400 frames? Blender 3.0 doesn't seem to have a 'bake' button anymore.

Thanks

Comment: For the rigid bodies you need to bake or delete the bake in the Scene panel > Rigid Body World > Cache

Comment: @moonboots Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For the rigid bodies you need to bake or delete the bake in the *Scene panel > Rigid Body World*